# Insert javascript code inside Jquery $().append();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I have the follow code:

```
for (var key in returns) {              
    $('#tBodyTable').append('\
        <tr>\
            <td >\
                <label>'+ returns[key].name +'</label>\
            </td>\
            <script>\
                for (var i in quant_colums){\
                    document.write("<td ><center><label>a</label></center></td>");\
               };\
            </script>\
        </tr>\
  ');
};
```

This code are inside the `return` of Jquery Ajax, and the first loop overwrite the `body` the table dynamically. T**he second loop is for create `<td>` dynamically based the value of the variable `quant_columns`, that is why has a javascript there.** But I don't know how exactly to do this. Each line of the table will have a number of the columns in determined point, based the result of the query.

How I can do it?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this, you want the index in `quant_colums` to be displayed in the label?

Comment: ES5 doesn't support multiline strings literals. You could use ES6 string interpolation.

Comment: @Adjit Hun Yes, actually put a number input type

Comment: @MinusFour how will i can do it?

Comment: @LucasCosta first, not a hun... second, why do you need to add a script? You're already using JavaScript, why not make the computation using your current script file instead of injecting your HTML with a script?

Comment: @Adjit Instead of you vote down, why not proposes a solution to be answering my question with other questions? If I'm asking is because I have not found something that satisfies me in the forum or on the internet.

Comment: @LucasCosta no downvote from me. I was just asking you why you were doing something in order to come up with a solution that works best for you. Wasn't too sure what your question was. No need to be obnoxious. Won't do you any good here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, you do not need to insert a script tag, you can do everything you need in the same function.

```js
$(function(){

    var returns = {t1: {name:'teste1'},t2:{name:'teste2'},t3:{name:'teste2'}};
    var quant_colums = 3;

    var $table = $('#tBodyTable');

    for (var key in returns) {     
        var $tr =  '<tr>\
      <td >\
                      <label>'+ returns[key].name +'</label>\
                  </td>\
              </tr>';
        
        for (var i in quant_colums){
            $tr.append("<td ><center><label>a</label></center></td>");
        }
        $table.append($tr);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tBodyTable"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks @alexqoliveira, this logic works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM to insert elements dynamically based on the data you have like this.

```js
var returns, quant_colums, tbody;

returns = {
  a: {name: "a"},
  b: {name: "b"},
  c: {name: "c"}
};

quant_colums = [0, 1, 2, 3];

tbody = window.document.querySelector("#tBodyTable");

Object.keys(returns).forEach(function (key) {
  var row, cell;

  row = tbody.insertRow();

  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.innerHTML = '<label>' + returns[key].name + '</label>';

  quant_colums.forEach(function (i) {
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.innerHTML = "<center><label>" + i + "</label></center>";
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody id="tBodyTable"></tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```